# Line break in a word document with Win32Com

Tags: python, replace, ms-word, win32com

I'm using the module Win32Com to edit automatically Word Documents with Python. But I'm facing an annoying problem that you've probably seen before : I use the Find and Replace function of the module to insert paragraphs into a template that I have, but sometimes I'd like to insert several paragraphs at the same time, which are separated with a line-break. The python string of these paragraphs is something like that : `text = "First paragraph.\nSecond paragraph."`

But the problem is that when I use the Find and Replace function with that kind of strings, it doesn't make a line-break but something like `First paragraph         Second paragraph`, which is obviously not what I want.

Does someone have an idea on how to deal with that ?

Thanks guys for help !

Comment: Maybe you need to specify Windows line breaks (`"\r\n"`)? – I'm just guessing...

Comment: If might also be ^p. To use that you might need to turn on wildcards in search/replace

Comment: Replacing `"\n"` by `"^p\n"` made perfectly the job ! Thanks very much for your help xidgel !